# Form is not submitted in a table into a JSP

Tags: forms, jsp, form-submit

I have the following code into a Jsp where i generate dynamically a table according to the parameter values that i retrieve from Data Base. i want to have an edit button next to each row and by pressing submit i want to submit a form to my servlet.
however i cannot put a  inside a  and  and i want a help.. here is the code:

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Surname</th>
                    <th>Customer Email</th>
                    <th>Customer Adress</th>
                    <th>Customer Contact Details</th>


                </tr>

                <c:forEach items="${ccustomers}" var="customer" >

                    <tr>
                           <form  action="myController" method="POST">
                        <td><input value="${customer.customerName}" name="customerNameEdit"/></td>
                        <td><input value="${customer.customerSurname}" name="searchForCustomerSurName"/></td>
                        <td><input value="${customer.email}" name="customerEmailEdit"/></td>
                        <td><input value="${customer.adress}" name="customerAdressEdit"/></td>
                        <td><input value="${customer.phoneNumber}" name="customerPhoneEdit"/></td>
                        <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.PARAM_PAGENAME%>" value="searchPage"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.SEARCHCRITERIA%>" value="customers"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="customerIdForEdit" value="${customer.customerId}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.RESULTPAGEPARAM%>" value="edit"/>
                      </form>
                </tr>

            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your button and other hidden fields into the last table column. It should be like that:

```
<form  action="myController" method="POST">
<tr>
   <td><input value="${customer.customerName}" name="customerNameEdit"/></td>
   <td><input value="${customer.customerSurname}" name="searchForCustomerSurName"/></td>
   <td><input value="${customer.email}" name="customerEmailEdit"/></td>
   <td><input value="${customer.adress}" name="customerAdressEdit"/></td>
   <td><input value="${customer.phoneNumber}" name="customerPhoneEdit"/></td>
   <td>
       <input type="button" value="edit" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.PARAM_PAGENAME%>" value="searchPage"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.SEARCHCRITERIA%>" value="customers"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="customerIdForEdit" value="${customer.customerId}"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="<%=WebParamsList.RESULTPAGEPARAM%>" value="edit"/>
   </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: hi Alex,

it seems that this one doesn't solve the problem i still have problem, any alternative?